# Delete Channel getStream API flutter

Tags: flutter, message, getstream-io, getstream-chat

I am building a messaging system in my flutter app using the get stream api. Right now, I want to delete a channel in case two users stop being friends or a user deletes their account. The documentation is not very clear on how to delete a single channel in flutter.

Here's what I have now, but I get an error saying **The method 'delete' isn't defined for the type 'ChannelState'**:

```
var channel = await client.queryChannel('messaging', channelId: widget.channel);
await channel.delete();
```

Seems pretty simple but I can't get it to work. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`client.queryChannels` is used to fetch a list of channels and it returns the channel state data class and not the Channel client.

We suggest querying a single channel using

```dart
final channel = client.channel('messaging', id: widget.channel);
await channel.watch(); // if you don't need to watch the channel you can even use channel.query()
```

Using

```dart
channel.delete()
```

you can delete the channel.

Comment: how can do same for Querying all users from server.
 I am using  streamClient.queryUsers 
and I am getting this error The argument type 'Future<QueryUsersResponse>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ValueListenable<PagedValue<Object?, Object?>>'.